# implementing java interface on Android

Tags: android, interface, listener

I've a problem to implement a java interface on my Android app...
The app crashes when the event is called. Specifically, on line "listener.callBack(String.valueOf(stringListValue.get(position)));"
This is the Logcat:

```
03-29 15:23:38.659  12568-12568/com.robertot.timereport E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.robertot.timereport, PID: 12568
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.robertot.timereport.com.robertot.timereport.pages.MainActivity$2.onItemSelected(MainActivity.java:231)
            at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:893)
            at android.widget.AdapterView.access$200(AdapterView.java:48)
            at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:861)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5081)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
            at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is the MainActivity:

```
    public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
        {
            //[...]

            private OnSelectItemSpinner listener;

            public interface OnSelectItemSpinner
            {
                public void callBack(String idjob);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { //[...] 
}

        //[...]
        ArrayAdapter<String> spnAdapt = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, stringListName);
                    spnAdapt.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    spnJobList.setAdapter(spnAdapt);
                    spnJobList.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long id)
                        {
                            switch (FragmentTag)
                            {
                                //Summary - Refresh ListView
                                case 0:
//CRASH HERE...
                                    listener.callBack(String.valueOf(stringListValue.get(position)));
                                    break;
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0){}
                    });
    //[...]
```

This is the Fragment when I call the interface:

```
public class SummaryFragment extends Fragment implements MainActivity.OnSelectItemSpinner 
{

@Override
    public void callBack(String idjob)
    {
        //do work
    }
}
```

When I wrong??

Thank you!!!

Comment: What line is the NPE on?

Comment: Sorry! the line is "listener.callBack(String.valueOf(stringListValue.get(position)));"

Comment: Don't put it here.. edit your question.

Comment: Anyways, your `listener` is probably null. I don't see it being used anywhere besides that line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to communicate between activity and fragments you must notice to this tip:
To allow a **Fragment** to communicate up to its **Activity**, you can define an **interface** in the **Fragment** class and implement it within the **Activity**. The Fragment captures the interface implementation during its **onAttach()** lifecycle method and can then call the Interface methods in order to communicate with the Activity.

Please refer to [Communicating Between Activity and Fragment](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

If you want to communicate in reverse you can do this code:

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

    public void callBack() {
        // Do SomeThing
    }
}


public class MainActivity extends Activity { 

    public void callFragmentCallBack() {
        MainFragment fragment = (MainFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_main);
        fragment.callBack(); // This line is important
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! I've just read your refer...So, I need to define an interface "from activity to fragment" and not "from fragment to activity"...I suppose to understand your reply, but I'm new on implementing java interface...

Comment: ah oK!! Thanks!! So, is not necessary a custom listener?

Comment: With this condition you don't need any interface but you must pay attention to this thing that **Fragment** must be visible or must be initialiazed before calling fragment's methods.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `NullPointerException` because You don't initialize `listener` anywhere.

```
OnSelectItemSpinner listener = new OnSelectItemSpinner()
{
    @Override
    public void callBack(String idjob)
    {
        // Do smth
    }
};
```

Comment: mmm...ok thanks! :) one question: Where does I insert the initialize? In fragment or activity? Both, I receive the message "OnSelectItemSpinner is abstract; cannot be istantiated"..